# Mac OS X: dircolors not found?

Tags: shell, osx, coreutils

I just switched to a Macbook Air. I installed zsh using homebrew, but when I use some of the code that I (originally had) in my `.zshrc`, I get an error saying that `.dircolors was not found`.

Below is the code in question:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' auto-description 'specify: %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _correct _approximate
zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
eval "$(dircolors -b)"
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ''
zstyle ':completion:*' list-prompt %SAt %p: Hit TAB for more, or the character to insert%s
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=* l:|=*'
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=long
zstyle ':completion:*' select-prompt %SScrolling active: current selection at %p%s
zstyle ':completion:*' use-compctl false
zstyle ':completion:*' verbose true

zstyle ':completion:*:*:kill:*:processes' list-colors '=(#b) #([0-9]#)*=0=01;31'
zstyle ':completion:*:kill:*' command 'ps -u $USER -o pid,%cpu,tty,cputime,cmd'
```

Is `dircolors` not shipped with Mac OS X? How should I install it?

## Update:

If I run dircolors directly on the shell I get:

`bash: dircolors; command not found`

Comment: Are you sure that it's really this code that causes the error? Only the `dircolors -b` seems suspicious, but on my computer it works without a `~/.dircolors` file just fine.

Comment: Try to run `dircolors` manually in a shell to see if the binary exists and is located in the `$PATH`.

Comment: Is the error really `.dircolors was not found` and not about `dircolors`? There is no `dircolors` command on OSX unless you installed it yourself, it's specific to Linux (or more accurately to GNU coreutils).

Comment: Thanks @Gilles. When I type in the shell `dircolors` I get: `bash: dircolors: command not found`. The code I posted in the OP was automatically generated by Zsh on a Linux machine. I thought I could clone my `.zshrc` to my Mac OS X directly. Do you know what the code in my OP does or have any suggestions on how to modify it to bring the equivalent functionality to Mac OS X?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The command `dircolors` is specific to GNU coreutils, so you'll find it on non-embedded Linux and on Cygwin but not on other unix systems such as OSX. The generated settings in your `.zshrc` aren't portable to OSX.

Since you're using the default colors, you can pass an empty string to the
[`list-colors`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-list_002dcolors_002c-completion-style) to get colors in file completions.

For colors with the [actual `ls` command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html), set the `CLICOLOR` environment variable on OSX, and also set `LSCOLORS` (see the manual for the format) if you want to change the colors.

```
if whence dircolors >/dev/null; then
  eval "$(dircolors -b)"
  zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
  alias ls='ls --color'
else
  export CLICOLOR=1
  zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ''
fi
```

If you wanted to set non-default colors (`dircolors` with a file argument), my recommendation would be to hard-code the output of `dircolors -b ~/.dircolors` in your `.zshrc` and use these settings for both zsh and GNU ls.

```
LS_COLORS=…
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
if whence dircolors >/dev/null; then
  export LS_COLORS
  alias ls='ls --color'
else
  export CLICOLOR=1
  LSCOLORS=…
fi
```

Comment: GNU `dircolors` is provided as `gdircolors` by `brew`'s `coreutils` package.

Comment: For example, I am trying `LS_COLORS=$LS_COLORS:'ex=1;30:ln=36' ; export LS_COLORS; ls` but it won't change the coloring when I do `ls`

Comment: @alper You need to pass an option to `ls` to make it use colors. This is typically done with an alias. Also note that `LS_COLORS` only influences GNU ls, not e.g. the native `ls` on macOS.

Comment: I am able to mak `ls` use colors in macOS, but I can't change the colors. e.g. binary files shown as red but I couldn't figure out the way to change their colors

Comment: @alper MacOS `ls` uses a different environment variable than GNU ls. Read the man page.

Answer (score 17):

Since FreeBSD has no command `dircolor` and OS X has the base of FreeBSD you can't use it.

The simplest thing is to use

```
export CLICOLOR=YES
```

in your `.zshrc` and `.bashrc` and remove `eval "$(dircolors -b)"`. To change the colors you can use the environment variable `LSCOLORS`.
For example:

```
export LSCOLORS="Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad"
```

You can find out more about it in the man page with

```
man ls
```

An alternative to `export CLICOLOR=YES` is to use an alias for `ls`

```
alias ls=ls -G
```

Some suggested to install the GNU-Coreutils from Mac Ports, but in my opinion this is an overkill. You can find the port [here](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/coreutils/Portfilecoreutils/Portfile)

Comment: adding `export CLICOLOR=YES` and setting `LSCOLORS` seems like not make any change on my end

Answer (score 7):

I don't do the whole mac thing anymore, so I don't have anything to test with, but in the quest to get this working on FreeBSD, I managed to figure out how to get this working from ports. I recall OSX has stuff like `brew` and `macports` - Try installing the GNU coreutils from this if you really want `dircolors` to work. I also had to set an alias for `dircolors` to `gdircolors` as this is the command that FreeBSD ports installed the fun as. Good luck to anyone who ends up trying this out!

Here's a link to someone getting the coreutils down via brew:

http://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 7):

You can install `dircolors` from Homebrew coreutils package:

```
 brew install coreutils
```

However, GNU coreutils are not included in the `PATH` by default. Edit your `~/.zshrc`, `~/.bashrc` and add:

```
  export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

Now after starting a new shell session `dircolors` should work.

Comment: This confused me until now. I thought it would be a separate package. Nice to see that dircolors is considered core :)

Comment: It is because all of these tools are maintained by GNU Core Utils project https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/ - apple does not allow anything GPL with any of their system.